# Java3d. How to increase range of sight?

Tags: java, java-3d

If I create a simple application where I can fly over a plain I can only see a little of the plain. The engine only renders in a certain radius around the camera. Everything that's beyond appears in the background colour. So it feels like being in a fog where my range of sight is only a couple of meters.

How do I increase that range of sight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javax.media.j3d.View.setFrontClipDistance(double distance)
```

More data found here:
http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/View.html

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this seems a bit late but I want to clarify for future reference the best answer is not exactly correct.

setFrontClipDistance Is the point that something un-renders as you get close to it, by default
this value is .01(meters) as you do not want something to un-render when you are 10 meters from it, well at least in most cases.

What is truly being asked is the how to increase the Maximum render distance and that is done with setBackClipDistance, default set to 10(meters). If you set it to 1000 then that would increase the maximum render distance to 1000 scale meters.

The proper way to set this, assuming you are using a simpleUnivers object, is to access the function in the View of the instanced object.

```
//Create a Simple Universe object using a 3d canvas object you have
SimpleUniverse simpleU = new SimpleUniverse(Your3dCanvasHere);

//add in your compiled branch group
simpleU.addBranchGraph(YourBranchGroupHere);

//Increase the render distance with setBackClipDistance
simpleU.getViewer().getView().setBackClipDistance(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to develop something serious, you shouldn't stick to Java-3D. Try to use OpenGL. OpenGL comes with a function:

```
gluPerspective(fieldOfViewY, aspect, near, far);
```

The far parameter is what you are looking for. OpenGL is way more efficient than a CPU based drawing engine, because it uses the GPU.

Comment: Java3D is using the GPU, isn't it? But it encapsulate the functions from the underlying OpenGL and DirectX interface and therefore it needs significant time until new functions of these interfaces are available through the Java3D-API.